# How to find the start and the end of sequences automatically in R for rectangles in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, rectangles

I am trying to plot some data with some shadow rectangles.

The dataframe `df` looks like this:

```
df <- data.frame(time  = seq(0.1, 2, 0.1), 
                 speed = c(seq(0.5, 5, 0.5), seq(5, 0.5, -0.5)),
                 type  = c("a", "a", "b", "b", "b", "b", "c", "c", "c", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "c", "a", "b", "c", "b", "b"))
```

For the rectangles in the plot I am defining an object called `dfRect` with the variables `xmin` and `xmax`.

```
dfRect <- data.frame(xmin = c(0.3, 1.0, 1.9), xmax = c(0.7, 1.5, 2.0))
```

The problem is I have to find `xmin` and `xmax` manually for the start and the end of the rectangles. A rectangle starts (`xmin`) at the start of a time sequence of `b` in column `type` and ends at the end of the same time sequence of `b`. Single `b`s can be ignored.

Here is the plot so you get an Idea what I am trying to accomplish:

```
ggplot() +
  geom_rect(data = dfRect, 
            aes(xmin = xmin, xmax = xmax, ymin = -Inf, ymax = Inf), 
            fill = "yellow", alpha = 0.4) +
  geom_line(data = df, aes(x = time, y = speed, color = type, group = 1), size = 3)
```

So in the end the question is. How can I automate the process of defining `xmin` and `xmax` and create dfRect automatically so I don't have to define it by myself?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an approach using run length encoding.

```r
library(ggplot2)

df <- data.frame(time  = seq(0.1, 2, 0.1), 
                 speed = c(seq(0.5, 5, 0.5), seq(5, 0.5, -0.5)),
                 type  = c("a", "a", "b", "b", "b", "b", "c", "c", "c", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "c", "a", "b", "c", "b", "b"))

# Convert to runlength encoding
rle <- rle(df$type == "b")

# Ignoring the single "b"s
rle$values[rle$lengths == 1 & rle$values] <- FALSE

# Determine starts and ends
starts <- {ends <- cumsum(rle$lengths)} - rle$lengths + 1

# Build a data.frame from the rle
dfrect <- data.frame(
  xmin = df$time[starts],
  # We have to +1 the ends, because the linepieces end at the next datapoint
  # Though we should not index out-of-bounds, so we need to cap at the last end
  xmax = df$time[pmin(ends + 1, max(ends))],
  fill = rle$values
)
```

This plot gives an idea what we've been doing in the code above:

```
ggplot() +
  geom_rect(data = dfrect, 
            aes(xmin = xmin, xmax = xmax, ymin = -Inf, ymax = Inf, fill = fill), 
            alpha = 0.4) +
  geom_line(data = df, aes(x = time, y = speed, color = type, group = 1), size = 3)
```

[image]

To get what you want you'd need to filter out the `FALSE`s.

```r
ggplot() +
  geom_rect(data = dfrect[dfrect$fill,], 
            aes(xmin = xmin, xmax = xmax, ymin = -Inf, ymax = Inf), 
            alpha = 0.4, fill = "yellow") +
  geom_line(data = df, aes(x = time, y = speed, color = type, group = 1), size = 3)
```

[image]

If you are looking for a stat that can calculate this for you, have a look [here](https://github.com/teunbrand/ggh4x/issues/12). Disclaimer: I wrote that function, which does a similar thing to the code I posted above.

Comment: Hah, I was about to post another solution with rle :) I think I'll post it nevertheless, it's a tiny bit different

Comment: Yeah sure go again, would be interesting to compare :)

Comment: @teunbrand, great answer! works like a charm with my data :) I like your solution also because of your stat_rle function on github. very useful

Answer (score 3):

Another approach with `rle`, but using data.table::rleid.

The pivoting idea is from Stefan!

I am sure the pipe could be further shortened somehow

```r
library(tidyverse)
df <- data.frame(
  time = seq(0.1, 2, 0.1),
  speed = c(seq(0.5, 5, 0.5), seq(5, 0.5, -0.5)),
  type = c("a", "a", "b", "b", "b", "b", "c", "c", "c", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "c", "a", "b", "c", "b", "b")
)
dfRect <-
  df %>%
  arrange(time, type) %>%
  mutate(id = data.table::rleid(type)) %>%
  group_by(type, id) %>%
  slice(c(1, n())) %>%
  distinct(time, id) %>%
  filter(type == "b" & n() > 1) %>%
  mutate(row = row_number()) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = row, names_prefix = "x", values_from = time)

ggplot() +
  geom_rect(
    data = dfRect,
    aes(xmin = x1, xmax = x2, ymin = -Inf, ymax = Inf),
    fill = "yellow", alpha = 0.4
  ) +
  geom_line(data = df, aes(x = time, y = speed, color = type, group = 1), size = 3)
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Try this. I added some explanatory comments inside the code:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(ggplot2)

df <- data.frame(time  = seq(0.1, 2, 0.1), 
                 speed = c(seq(0.5, 5, 0.5), seq(5, 0.5, -0.5)),
                 type  = c("a", "a", "b", "b", "b", "b", "c", "c", "c", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "c", "a", "b", "c", "b", "b"))

dfRect <- df %>% 
  arrange(time, type) %>% 
  # Get start and end of sequences
  mutate(is_b_start = type == "b" & lag(type) != "b",
         is_b_end = type != "b" & lag(type) == "b") %>% 
  filter(is_b_start | is_b_end) %>%
  # Get id of sequences
  mutate(id = cumsum(is_b_start),
         type = ifelse(is_b_start, "min", "max")) %>% 
  select(time, id, type) %>%
  # To wide format gives xmin and xmax for each sequence 
  tidyr::pivot_wider(names_from = type, names_prefix = "x", values_from = time) %>% 
  # In case: Fill last with max time
  tidyr::replace_na(list(xmax = max(df$time)))
  
ggplot() +
  geom_rect(data = dfRect, 
            aes(xmin = xmin, xmax = xmax, ymin = -Inf, ymax = Inf), 
            fill = "yellow", alpha = 0.4) +
  geom_line(data = df, aes(x = time, y = speed, color = type, group = 1), size = 3)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-06-21 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>