# Create automatically multiple rectangles between limit values - in ggplot R

Tags: r, ggplot2

I would like to plot rectangles between specific values listed in a data frame, such as:

```
 Region <- c("A","B","A","B","A","C","B","C","A"),
  Lon <- c(31.03547, 37.25443, 65.97450, 69.90290, 101.77630,
                 105.32550, 148.86270, 147.72010, 146.10420)
  var1 <- rnorm(n = 9, mean = 15, sd = 100)
  regions <- data.frame(Region, Lon, var1)
```

This is an example where I show the region limits using `geom_vline`:

```
 ggplot(NULL)+
  geom_vline(data = regions, aes(xintercept=Lon, 
                                 linetype=region,
                                 color = region),
             size=0.6)+
  geom_point(data = regions, aes(x=Lon, y=var1, color=Region))+
  theme_bw()
```

I want to plot background rectangles that would be limited by those verticle lines.

I tried to look at this previous question:
[How to find the start and the end of sequences automatically in R for rectangles in ggplot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62501914/how-to-find-the-start-and-the-end-of-sequences-automatically-in-r-for-rectangles)
However, it does not satisfy completely my needs, because I would like to plot rectangles for every region.

```
# Convert to runlength encoding
rle <- rle(regions$Region == "B")

# Determine starts and ends
starts <- {ends <- cumsum(rle$lengths)} - rle$lengths + 1

# Build a data.frame from the rle
dfrect <- data.frame(
  xmin = regions$Lon[starts],
  # We have to +1 the ends, because the linepieces end at the next datapoint
  # Though we should not index out-of-bounds, so we need to cap at the last end
  xmax = regions$Lon[pmin(ends + 1, max(ends))],
  fill = rle$values
)

ggplot(NULL)+
  geom_vline(data = regions, aes(xintercept=Lon, 
                                 linetype=region,
                                 color = region),
             size=0.6)+
  geom_rect(data = dfrect, 
            aes(xmin = xmin, xmax = xmax, ymin = -Inf, ymax = Inf,
                fill = fill), 
            alpha = 0.4) +
  geom_point(data = regions, aes(x=Lon, y=var1, color=Region))+
   theme_bw()
```

How can I define the rectangles for A and C too? consider that I have multiple regions, not only 3.

Comment: Change to a 3 levels rle, as in `rle <- rle(regions$Region)` and see if it does what you need. The only problem II'm seeing is that the rectangles do not go up to the end of the plot, there are blank areas at the beginning and at the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**sample data**

```
Region <- c("A","B","A","B","A","C","B","C","A")
Lon <- c(31.03547, 37.25443, 65.97450, 69.90290, 101.77630,
         105.32550, 148.86270, 147.72010, 146.10420)
var1 <- rnorm(n = 9, mean = 15, sd = 100)
regions <- data.frame(Region, Lon, var1)
```

**code**

```
library(data.table)
# Make regions a data.table
setDT(regions)
# first sort by lon, to avoind overlap in rectangles
setkey(regions, Lon)
# create boundaries of rectangles
regions[, Lon_end := data.table::shift(Lon, type = "lead", fill = Inf)][]
# plot
ggplot(data = regions) +
  geom_vline(aes(xintercept = Lon, linetype = Region, color = Region), size = 0.6) +
  geom_rect(mapping = aes(xmin = Lon, xmax = Lon_end, ymin = 0, ymax = 1, fill = Region), alpha = 0.1)
```

**output**

[image]